# Opshub conversion troubles to Visual Studio online and converting DOS (8.3) short paths

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to convert our repository from TFS 2012 on-premise to Visual Studio Online.

I am getting errors like this:

OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF203013: The path O:\somepath\Jeffkn~1.jpg is in the DOS (8.3) short path format and is not supported. Enter a full path to the item and try again.

I believe we did this during our migration back in the day (method 2):
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951195 
Which is to add `<add key="allow8Dot3Paths" value="true" />` to our TFS temporarily during a migration.

How do I accomplish this today with Visual Studio Online / OpsHub?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The path contains a file name that is in the MS-DOS-compatible short name format (in your case is **Jeffkn~1.jpg**), you need to change the path to rename the Jeffkn~1.jpg file, for example **Jeffkn.jpg**.

Additionally, you can't take Method2 in the KB article to enable TFS2012 Application Tier server to allow the MS-DOS-compatible short name format, because there is no problem to have this path in on-premise TFS, you have the problem when migrate item to VSO. So, you need to enable the MS-DOS-compatible short name format for VSO, but I don't think you have permissions to do it.

Comment: I don't think I can correct the problem by renaming. This is in my TFS history already, this file has been since deleted. My current branch does not have this file anymore. I am hoping there is a way to flip this allow8Dot3Paths some way on VSOnline.

Comment: @BrianPeterson, I don't think there is a way to enable the MS-DOS-compatible short name format for VSO. You can consider submit one feature request about it on the Microsoft UserVoice site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server-visual-studio-online . Now, you have to correct the error via changing the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Could you Please try below steps, it might help
    First close the migration utility then add the app setting key "allow8Dot3Paths" to devenv.exe.config ("c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE) or in "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

```
Under the <configuration> element, locate the <appSettings> element, and then add the following element.

    <add key="allow8Dot3Paths" value="true" /> 

in the devenv.exe.config file.


Now start the migration utility, start the migration and retry the failure, wait for the retry to complete and if you still get the error then please email us the OpsHubTFSService.log file from location "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs" to support@opshub.com
```